# Matrix Synapse matrix-appservice-irc messages only travel from IRC to Matrix

Tags: linux, debian, bridge, irc, matrix

My irc bridge has connected the rooms i wanted, except messages are only passed from irc to matrix! Also the matrix[m] users are not appearing in the irc chatroom.

Here are my configs:

**$ cat config.yaml**

```
# Configuration specific to AS registration. Unless other marked, all fields
# are *REQUIRED*.
homeserver:
  # The URL to the home server for client-server API calls, also used to form the
  # media URLs as displayed in bridged IRC channels:
  url: "http://localhost:8008"


  # The 'domain' part for user IDs on this home server. Usually (but not always)
  # is the "domain name" part of the HS URL.
  domain: "perthchat.org"

# Configuration specific to the IRC service
ircService:
  servers:
    # The address of the server to connect to.
    chat.freenode.net:
      # A human-readable short name. This is used to label IRC status rooms
      # where matrix users control their connections.
      # E.g. 'ExampleNet IRC Bridge status'.
      # It is also used in the Third Party Lookup API as the instance `desc`
      # property, where each server is an instance.
      name: "FreeNode"

      #additionalAddresses: [ "irc2.example.com" ]


  mappings:
    # 1:many mappings from IRC channels to room IDs on this IRC server.
    # The matrix room must already exist. Your matrix client should expose
    # the room ID in a "settings" page for the room.
    #"#thepub": ["!kieouiJuedJoxtVdaG:localhost"]
    "#Perth": ["!kqNjXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org"]
    "##perthcrypto": ["!iAnyMXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org"]
    "##perthfosschurch": ["!DSIYXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org"]
    "##perthfishing": ["!EcHSXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org"]
    "##sayhello": ["!DwUPXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org"]
```

**$ cat my_registration_file.yaml**

```
  id: 1ebdXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    hs_token: 9561XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    as_token: 9883XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    namespaces:
      users:
        - exclusive: true
          regex: '@irc_.*:perthchat.org'
      aliases:
        - exclusive: true
          regex: '#irc_.*:perthchat.org'
      rooms:
        - exclusive: false
          regex: '!DSIYXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org'
        - exclusive: false
          regex: '!DwUPXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org'
        - exclusive: false
          regex: '!EcHSXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org'
        - exclusive: false
          regex: '!iAnyMXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org'
        - exclusive: false
          regex: '!kqNjXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:perthchat.org'
    url: 'http://localhost:9999/'
    sender_localpart: my_bot
    rate_limited: false
    protocols:
      - irc
```

This was the command used to run it in tmux:

```
$ node app.js -c config.yaml -f my_registration_file.yaml -p 9999
```

Room id's and tokens have been edited. Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong? :p

Comment: Do you have +m on your IRC channel?